# Lowercase variable values in a Puppet template

Tags: puppet, strings

In my puppet config I need to lowercase a variable value before using it in a template. How to achieve this? Is there a way to lowercase a variable value inside the puppet manifest? Do I need to do this in the template?

And more general: where are string manipulation functions that I could use in manifests.

Do I have to write my own custom ruby functions to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Puppet's string manipulation capabilities inside manifests are very limited.  Manifests aren't really intended to handle stuff like this.

But, in the template, it's easy; normal ruby functions are available.  Say I wanted a lowercase of the `osfamily` fact:

```
<%= osfamily.downcase %>
```

Answer (score 17):

There are two general solutions I can think of for this problem.  By general, I mean they'll work in manifest files and templates instead of just templates.

The solution I recommend is to use the `downcase()` parser function in the [standard library module](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib).  I recommend this because you don't need to write any ruby code and it's easier to read:

```
class helloworld {
  $os_downcase = downcase($osfamily)
}
include helloworld
```

If you don't want to depend on the `stdlib` module, then you can use the `inline_template` function to generalize the solution Shane mentioned:

```
class helloworld {
  $os_downcase = inline_template('<%= osfamily.downcase %>')
}
include helloworld
```

`inline_template` avoids the need to create a separate `*.erb` file.

Hope this helps.
-Jeff